# bashrc - variables with spaces for lazyness

Tags: bash, variables, spaces

I'd like to setup something like this in my .bashrc

```
export p1=`eval echo ~/projects/customer name/project name`
export p2=`eval echo ~/projects/customerb name/project name`
```

typing `cd $p1` fails due to the spaces & I get directory not found issues.

I am aware that typing `cd "$p1"` (*with speechmarks around variables*) works.

How do I correctly setup my vars so that I can do things like this...

```
cd $p2
cp $p1/file $p2/
open $p1/lib
```

...**without** typing speechmarks each time?

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Comment: Why are you assigning the results of `$(eval echo ...)`? What do you think `eval` is doing for you?

Comment: I thought I needed eval to expand the ~ ... just checked.. you're right, I didn't need it :)

Comment: The variables don't need to be exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good idea. You should learn to deal with the shell as it is rather than rely on hacks to get behavior you find more aesthetically pleasing.

That said, you can achieve the effect you want by removing space from the `IFS` variable when assigning `p1`

Sample:

```
IFS= p1="/path with/some/spaces in/it"
ls -l $p1
```

Now it goes without saying, but I will say anyway to be clear, that you should not unset `IFS` and leave it that way; most of the time the result won't be what you expect. You should do so only for specific commands.

Also, the term you're looking for is "double-quote", not "speechmark." When googling, asking questions and searching for documentation in general it's better to use the correct jargon.

EDIT:

Copy-paste friendly version:

```
IFS= export p1="$HOME/projects/customer name/project name"
cd $p1
```

Comment: I like the fact you edited this to understand the *good reason* ;)

Thanks for your post, you've cleared up why my google searches are struggling to find a solution.

Kind Regards,  
Nick

Comment: "You should learn to deal with the shell as it is rather than rely on hacks to get behavior you find more aesthetically pleasing." What do you say about having to type very annoying paths 100 times a day? *still* use the shell as it is? I do not agree there -- custumization is key to learning the shell.

Comment: @rody_o: No. You should simply quote the expansions.

Comment: Why then? What's your reasons? You don't provide any. Flagging as unconstructive.

Comment: @rody_o: The correct way to achieve the effect the requester wants, that of variables with spaces expanded with the spaces preserved literally, is to double quote the variables when expanding. Asking for another way to do this is asking for trouble. My solution abuses shell features in a fragile way to achieve the effect, but it is not the correct solution. The correct solution is to use the shell the way it is intended to be used, or to find a shell that behaves differently (and good luck with that). This entire question is nonconstructive as is any answer to (except for "Don't do that.")

Comment: You repeat yourself in different wording without providing actual *reasons*. "correct" way, "asking for trouble", etc. are *not* reasons; they are *opinions*. Please provide concrete examples and I'll shut up :p

Comment: @rody_o: I thought that *correctness* was a self-evident virtue without any belaboring needed. I thought you were misunderstanding the incorrectness of my solution. I apologize. You should not abuse the shell this way because: 1) It will teach you to expect abnormal behavior from expansions, which will lead to you making mistakes in other places, which will lead to bugs. Bugs are bad because they make things not work as they should and can have harmful side-effects. I don't think it's necessary to explain why bugs are bad, but I didn't think it was necessary to explain why correctness is good!

Comment: @rody_o: 2) It actually *won't work* for all possible values in the variable. Sample: a literal * in the path in the variable will not be treated literally on expansion. Is this what you expected? Maybe, but it's certainly not what *I* expect and could lead to bugs when globbing happens where it "shouldn't".

Comment: For future reference -- "correctness" is a reason, but tinckering with IFS is "correct" as well. In short, being more verbose, especially in threads like this, is more constructive.

Comment: In shell scripts, I agree -- don't ever use this sort of hack. Most shell scripts, however temporary you think they are, tend to stick around and tend to be used on more and more machines over time, increasing the need for their portability. For manual system administration in a mixed Windows/Linux environment, where many directories contain spaces, dollar signs and what not, this sort of hack is a great timesaver, *IF* used with care. Remember -- no rule applies 100% of the time.

Comment: @rody_o: I disagree fundamentally. In a situation where many directories contain spaces, dollar signs and what-not, this hack is **absolotely wrong** and the user should double-quote the expansion. It *does not* save time to avoid this quoting. It is *much less* cognitively challenging to *not use care* with this hack and instead just *always do the right thing* and quote expansions. The experienced, knowledgeable shell scripter can decide when not to apply the "always double quote" rule -- he also doesn't post questions like this.

Comment: @rody_o: As a final thought: When teaching I encourage learners to learn and use some rules 100% of the time. If and when he learns enough to know that a rule should not be applied 100% of the time then he has the wit to know *when* it should not be applied. Some rules apply always, and by always I mean until you understand when they don't. Teaching anything else is more harmful than helpful.

Comment: Again, I see no concrete examples, only more "you should do this and that 'cause it's better". Better how? I fully understand the origin of the user's request -- I have to circumnavigate our whole network on a daily basis, and I have many such hacks for doing so. Hacks like these sure *are* a timesaver for copying stuff from a path going 29 subdirs deep, all with "windows style naming", to another such dir. Shortcuts like these (provided they are tested properly! and you know when to expand it!) make bugs actually *less* likely.

Comment: Also, regarding your view on teaching -- In my view, teaching "rules of thumb" rather than "dealing in absolutes" will indeed take longer, and the student will make more errors in the process. But the student will have learned *far more* and at a *far deeper level* at the end of that process, and will remember it all for much longer. I think we have found the roots of our little dispute! :)

Comment: @rody_o: I find your classification of "file names with spaces and other special characters" as "Windows style naming" to be offensive. As a shell scripter you are expected to allow any non-null value in file names, whereas in Windows many characters are not allowed in file names.

Comment: It's just an observation -- linux users tend to use underscores etc. to avoid issues like the one mentioned by the OP, simply because it is more CLI oriented. Windows users tend to use spaces in those places. Also, something like $RECYCLE_BIN\ or the the naming convention of subdirs in System Volume Information\ (among many others) is something you just don't see on linux systems...So yes, "windows style" file naming is an accurate shorthand for things not often seen on linux sytems. The fact that you take offense off that , well...that's really your problem.

Comment: But, we are soooo far off-topic...Let's just conclude this quirrel with: we just have different views on the issue. The SO community has decided that you have the better explanation. Congrats on that. Until the next bash discussion :)

Comment: I do not have a problem teaching rules of thumb, where appropriate, but some things *are* effectively absolutes. Again I reiterate that hacks like these *do not* save time, based on my experience. I am developing a poor view of your character from this exchange; I now assume that you're kind of programmer who does what's "good enough" and considers it a virtue, even when the potential defects are obvious ("But that will never happen, so it's OK.") This practice of needlessly trading correctness for simplicity or immediacy is abhorrent. I reiterate: **just quote expansions**! Why ever not?

Comment: Ah, you know...why trust compilers, why not write super-efficient assembler? 
I

Comment: "poor view of your character" wow...since when do one's programming practices fully describe one's character? C'mon, you win, don't turn somethign as futile as this into a powergame.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this easily by creating a function that places the quotes for you:

```
cdd(){
    command cd "$*"
}
```

now, if you type

```
ps1="some path /with lots /of spaces/"
cdd $ps1
```

This will indeed show the desired behavior.

Note that (as indicated in the other comments) this **may not work as intended** if the pathname in `$p1` contains special characters other than space -- *know* when to use it before using it.

Comment: Have you confirmed this by testing it?